# Wait first trigger to set value in second dropdown

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have my modal with a FORM and I need to check each input to set the value but I have a problem.

Since I have a dropdown State I need to set first the value in this dropdown and then wait for it to load the second dropdown and set the value (County).

I need actually to know if is possible have an answer that it is loaded and then run with the loop to set its value.

The code is working to load the others values.

Thank you!

```
$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var selects = $("#tbl_site").bootstrapTable('getSelections'); 

    var checkEdit = $(this).find("#modal-title").text();
    var data = JSON.stringify(selects);
    var result = data.substring(1, data.length - 1);
    var row = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

    if(checkEdit.indexOf('Edit') >= 0){                
        for (var name in row) {
            $("#myform").find('input[name="' + name + '"]').val(row[name]);
            $("#myform").find('select[name="' + name + '"]').val(row[name]).trigger('change');
        } 
    }            
});
```

Comment: if the loading of second dropdown is promisable, you can set the value (Country) upon when it has done loading

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or snippet or add full code. And you want to load second dropdown and then set its value. is it the case?

Comment: @ShalinPatel Yes. I want to load the second dropdown and then set the value for it.